# Python - Time data not match format

Tags: python, strptime

I have string time in the following format

`2016-12-10T13:54:15.294`

I am using the following method to format the time:

`time.strptime(ts, '%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')`

Which throws an error:
`time data did not match format:  data=2016-12-10T13:54:15.294  fmt=%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y`

Any ideas where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first parse the string as its formatted, then print it out the way you want.

```
>>> import datetime
>>> ts = "2016-12-10T13:54:15.294"
>>> parsed = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
>>> parsed
datetime.datetime(2016, 12, 10, 13, 54, 15, 294000)
>>> parsed.strftime('%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y')
'Dec 10 13:54:15 2016'
```

Comment: Thanks. I followed this and got another error now:
`KeyError: 'f'`

Comment: More Info: `Python 2.3.4`

Comment: Wow . Python 2.3! I didn't even know such a version was still in the wild. The reason its not working is because the `f` modifier was added in Python 2.6 - I would highly recommend you upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for the directions, I dod applied a workaround and it works for me. I know 2.3 is old, but this is legacy system and can't simply upgrade without accessing the complete impact!.

Answer (score 0):

I think your date format is incorrectly specified in string. This should work:

```
import datetime
a = '2016-12-10T13:54:15.294'
b= datetime.datetime.strptime(a,'%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
print b
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is not wrong, the format string is not even close to the string you're trying to parse.

You have `{year}-{month}-{day}T{hour}:{minute}:{second}.{milliseconds}` but trying to parse it with `{weekday name} {month name} {day} {hour}:{minute}:{second} {year}`. Did you copy this from somewhere?

[According to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior), your format string should look more like `%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f`.

```
>>> time.strptime('2016-12-10T13:54:15.294', '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f')
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=12, tm_mday=10, tm_hour=13, tm_min=54, tm_sec=15, tm_wday=5, tm_yday=345, tm_isdst=-1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your format string is not correct.

You can check format string just using [strftime](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) method of date object. For example:

```
d = datetime.datetime.now()
print(d.strftime('%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S'))
```

Output:

```
Dec 16 11:02:46 2016
```

But you have string in following format `2016-12-10T13:54:15.294`, so you just need to change [format](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) string:

```
print(time.strptime(ts, '%Y-%d-%mT%H:%M:%S.%f'))
```

output:

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2016, tm_mon=10, tm_mday=12, tm_hour=13, tm_min=54, tm_sec=15, tm_wday=2, tm_yday=286, tm_isdst=-1)
```